# How to make use of Office dev PnP provisioning template

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, css, responsive, pnp

I need some guidance on how to make use of the Office dev PnP provisioning template for SharePoint online. Basically, I am trying to make my SharePoint site responsive without tampering with the master page. I can't seem to find detailed information about how to achieve this.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but for future reference.

UI Responsive Package provided from PnP initiative, is using PnP Provisioning Template to apply needed customizations to SharePoint site to make it responsive.

Please see more information from following PnP web cast - http://dev.office.com/blogs/web-cast-responsive-ui-package-for-sharepoint